# Temporary role/privileges

Tags: postgresql, security

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to temporary grant roles/privileges to a user? I'm thinking about this as a solution for the situation when there is a need to troubleshoot an issue and an user may need some specific role/privileges (even superuser) only for a short period of time.

Comment: Have you looked into `noinherit`? With this it’s possible to setup your users so that they don’t get roles by default but can activate them when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GRANT` does not have an expiration date, but roles have. So:

```
CREATE ROLE foo VALID UNTIL '2019-05-01 00:00+02';

GRANT my_privilege_bundle TO foo;
```

And `my_privilege_bundle` would be a group role bundling all required privileges.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html)

> `VALID UNTIL 'timestamp'`
>
> The `VALID UNTIL` clause sets a date and time after which the role's password is no longer valid. If this clause is omitted the password will be valid for all time.

Note that this does not end existing sessions. The role just can't make new connections *with password* after the expiration date. [The manual once more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html)

> The `VALID UNTIL` clause defines an expiration time for a password only, not for the role per se. In particular, the expiration time is not enforced when logging in using a non-password-based authentication method.

Comment: I tested this approach and unfortunately it does not work, after the `VALID UNTIL` timestamp user `foo` still has the privileges from `my_privilege_bundle `

Comment: @Radu: Sure the role still has the same privileges. But it cannot log in any more. Like I said, no expiration date for `GRANT`.  Use a separate login for added privileges.